# Remove path from the create/edit a post view

Tags: visual-editor

Been fiddling around, trying to remove the "path" info that's shown when you create/edit a post in wordpress. Been able to remove word count and the saving draft info, but not the path thingie

This is what I'm talking about:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3618143/Sk%C3%A4rmavbild%202011-03-13%20kl.%2001.08.11.png

Also, the autosave-info that shows up on posts that's being edited. "Last edited by admin" etc. Can't seem to find that either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the filter `tiny_mce_before_init` to customise the default configuration;

```
function wpse_11867_tiny_mce( $config ) {
    $config['theme_advanced_path'] = false;
    return $config;
}

add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'wpse_11867_tiny_mce' );
```

Check out all the options available on the [Tiny MCE documentation](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration).

Comment: You wouldn't know how to get rid of the autosave-info aswell?
Can't find my way around the TinyMCE documentation

Comment: That's actually in WordPress core, and not part of TinyMCE. The code is in `wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php`, line 278 (for WordPress 3.1). I think the only way you can 'remove' it is to hide it with CSS.